# Random Vandermonde matrix

Tags: matrices, random-variables, random-matrices

I would like to analyze (behavior on condition number, distribution of eigen values etc) random Vandermonde matrices:

$$
V_{i,j} = \alpha_i^{j-1} 
$$

where $\alpha_i$ are *correlated* random variables. For simplicity, I can assume they are Gaussian and for simplicity I can assume $\in \mathbb{R}$ (which I would like to extend later to $\mathbb{C}$).

I found some material by Gabriel Tucci (http://ect.bell-labs.com/who/gtucci/publications/vander_final.pdf) for the case when the magnitude is one but I am specifically interested in the case when the magnitude of the variables is not one. Any pointer?

Comment: Hi! I hope it is not too late. I've been interested in the same topic. I didn't find anything for the case when the magnitude is different from one. I suggest you take a look at the material of Ryan Oyvind: https://folk.uio.no/oyvindry/talks.shtml